# Getting the type of an object when passing the object to a method

Tags: c#, object, methods

If you have an object `Foo` and you pass it to a method `void Bar(object obj)` and inside you test the type of the object using `typeof(obj)` will it return the typeof to be Foo or object?

Comment: fire up a compiler and see for yourself

Comment: Don't you have a compiler?

Comment: Neither; it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) on `obj`, it's for type names only, not instances. You need to use [`obj.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx), which will return the runtime type of `obj`. In your case, it would return an instance of [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) corresponding to `Foo` assuming that `obj` is an instance of `Foo` and not an instance of some type that derives from `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you need to use `obj.GetType()`.

[`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) is used to obtain the `Type` object of a type, for instance `typeof(int)`, whereas [`Object.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) obtains the `Type` of an instance of an object (runtime object).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, typeof is used to generic types. When you have a reference to an object instance you would typically just call .GetType()

To make sure I understand your questions...

```
var myFoo = new Foo();
Bar(myFoo);

....

void Bar(object myObject)
{
   Type aType = myObject.getType(); // aType will equal typeof(Foo)
```

Comment: "Usually, typeof is used to generic types." No, it's for when you need a `Type` object given a type name, not an instance.